# What does it mean that the listening callback for the 'net' module in nodejs is in setImmediate()?

Tags: node.js, libuv

I have a NodeJS event loop question.

link : https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#why-use-process-nexttick

The link says that the `listening` callback is in `setImmediate()`.

Does this mean that the callback is in the check phase queue?

When I looked at the `net` source code, I didn't see anything that used `setImmediate`.
net code : https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/61b4d60c5d/lib/net.js#L1407

Can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: it means the on listening listener needs to be called before it .listen()

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. Is that sentence saying that I should use `nextTick` because that's what happens if I use setImmediate? @Someone Special

Comment: code example pls

Comment: I'm talking about the code from the link in the body.